Редиректы файла .htaccess
Есть дубли страниц на сайте (т.е https://test/TEST1/test2/ выдает ответ 200, хотя ее настоящая ссылка это https://test/test1/test2/), написано правило

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z] RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /${tolower:$1}
[L,R=301]

которое вроде и должно работать, но не работает... Помогите!

Если эти "дубли" появляются в ПС - ты поломал каноникал, который ВП по дефолту делает. При наличии каноникала проблем с дублями нет.

достаточно просто установить на страницы каноникал?

Каноникал есть по умолчанию. Ты мог его поломать.

а как исправить то?

Да откуда ж мне знать где и как ты поломал. И поломал ли вообще, какой тип контента и есть ли в принципе проблема... Я не телепат, а ты даже адреса зашифровал.

ссылка https://usiminsk.by/yuridicheskie-uslugi/korporativnaya-praktika/  отдает ответ 200 по следующим ссылкам
1. https://usiminsk.by/yuridicheskie-uslugi/korporativnayaKORPORATIVNAYA-praktikaPRAKTIKA/
2. https://usiminsk.by/korporativnaya-praktika/yuridicheskie-uslugi/
3. https://usiminsk.by/YURIDICHESKIE-USLUGI/korporativnaya-praktika/
4. https://usiminsk.by/yuridicheskie-uslugi/KORPORATIVNAYA-PRAKTIKA/
5. https://usiminsk.by/yuridicheskie-uslugi/korporativnaya-praktika/Ve

Нет никакой проблемы. Либо 404 либо 301.  И каноникал на месте

сейчас глянул, именно эта ссылка редиректиться, вот актуальное:
https://usiminsk.by/yuridicheskie-uslugi/registraciya-kompanii/sozdanie-sovmestnogo-predpriyatiya/ нужная ссылка; ответ 200 по                     https://usiminsk.by/YURIDICHESKIE-USLUGI/registraciya-kompanii/sozdanie-sovmestnogo-predpriyatiya/
https://usiminsk.by/yuridicheskie-uslugi/REGISTRACIYA-KOMPANII/sozdanie-sovmestnogo-predpriyatiya/
https://usiminsk.by/yuridicheskie-uslugi/registraciya-kompanii/SOZDANIE-SOVMESTNOGO-PREDPRIYATIYA/

Ну и что? Каноникал правильный. Где "дубли"?

интересный вопрос... Я не знаю сам, с меня требуют пофиксить вот этот бред, но что и как я не понимаю

Это надуманная проблема. "Требуют" кто? небось говносершнеги? На самом деле проблемы нет, говносеошнеги придумывают несуществующие чтобы больше денег сорвать. О дублях можно говорить когда они появятся в ПС. А они не появятся. Доказательство тому- туча ВП-сайтов у которых тоже самое. Ида. на самом сайте не должно быть таких полукривых ссылок.

Если не получается настроить редирект через .htaccess, попробуй плагины, для редиректов их множество
И самое очевидное, но не исключенно: сервер точно Apache? В nginx .htaccess инструкции не работают

проблема в том что почти для каждой ссылки есть такая вот штука с регистром... У меня получается настроить редирект "одна ссылка одна строка", но это не работает для особого множества

Другие .htaccess инструкции работают?
